# Inserting Unicode values into SQLite

Tags: sqlite, unicode

I have some Unicode values (for Devnagri script) in an Excel sheet which I want to insert into SQLite using the SQLite database browser in Windows XP.

For example, when the Unicode value is `U+01F8`:

- If I use an insert statement such as `insert into table1(colmn1)
  values('U+01F8');` it inserts `U+01F8` as a string.
- If I use SQL like `insert into table1(colmn1) values(u'01F8');` the
  browser hangs up and I have to forcefully terminate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should just insert that character directly:

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1) VALUES('न')
```

Alternatively, encode the string in UTF-8 (U+01F8 would be C7 B8), write the bytes as a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue), and convert the blob back into a string in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1) VALUES(CAST(x'C7B8' AS TEXT))
```