# Insert Unicode symbols in Sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, unicode

I am trying to add Unicode symbols [found here](https://unicode-table.com/en/) in my Sqlite database through Sqlite database. I want to add the symbols using the Unicode code for each symbol. I came across the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958296/inserting-unicode-values-into-sqlite). Some of the symbols I can add them just with copy-paste. However, in some categories like [Emoticons (Emoji)](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/emoticons/) probably I have to add the codes from my sqlite browser. Which code should I add in my database?

I tried to add it using the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1) VALUES(CAST(x'C7B8' AS TEXT))
```

This code it works fine but when I add a code from the link provided it does not work.

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1) VALUES(CAST(x'U+1F600' AS TEXT))
```

I got the following error:

> unrecognized token: "x'U+1F600'":

How can I add the code in my db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x'...'` form is a blob literal, not text. When a blob is converted to text, it is assumed that it is a series of bytes that represents the UTF-8 encoding of the characters.

So you have to look up the hex values of the UTF-8 encoding:

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1) VALUES('');
INSERT INTO table1(column1) VALUES(CAST(x'F09F98BB' AS TEXT));
```